# Are Plane.Set3Points and Plane constructor with parameters no longer supported in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm getting a compilation error if I try to pass the parameter to the Plane constructor or when I try to call the Set3Points method. However, I see these everywhere on the internet and I've found no mention of people having this issue or acknowledging that this has changed so I'm in doubt, maybe I'm missing something simple. Maybe I need some library? Or maybe I'm not calling them correctly.

Links to documentation:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Set3Points.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane-ctor.html

Here's what I tried:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Plane : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(1f, 2f, 3f);
        Vector3 v2 = new Vector3(10f, 20f, 30f);

        Plane plane = new Plane(v1, v2);
    }
}
```

//Set3Points:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Plane : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        Plane plane = new Plane();

        Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(1f, 2f, 3f);
        Vector3 v2 = new Vector3(2f, 3f, 4f);
        Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(6f, 7f, 8f);

        plane.Set3Points(v1, v2, v3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the compilation error?  You aren't assigning values to your Vectors in the example code so if that's what you've written, it's not the way you're calling `Plane` functions, its a lack of proper input.
Edit: To answer your question, those `Plane` functions haven't changed and you don't need any extra libraries; they're still valid and exist in the UnityEngine core module.

Comment: Dammit.. yeah. that's not the issue. I just wrote that for this post and forgot initializing them. The error I'm getting now is in another language but it's that one "The method Plane has no constructor that takes 2 parameters". and when I'm trying to call Set3Points, VS acts as if I wrote something gibberish. Does it work for you?

Comment: Can you post the exact code that's causing the error and any relevant code around it?  It works just fine for me (and `Set3Points` must be called on a valid instance of a `Plane`, it's not a `static` method).

Comment: I'll do that right now, I'm intrigued now.

Comment: OK, this is for Plane constructor. As far as I understand, this should work correctly according to the documentation (check the code after "EDIT" in my post, also added the code with Set3Points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've named your behavior `Plane` so its looking for the constructor of *your* class.  You either need to rename your behavior to something else or specify that it's the `Plane` in `UnityEngine`:

```
UnityEngine.Plane plane = new UnityEngine.Plane(v1, v2);
```

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing! Thanks a lot! I even tried with other methods with other names but because I still had that Plane class Unity still thought I was referring to it. Can't believe I couldn't figure that out, thanks again.

Comment: No problem! It's an easy mistake to make that doesn't generate a helpful-enough error.